# PC turns on, monitor goes dark, fan still runs afterwards

Tags: graphics-card, display, motherboard, fan

I've been having this problem in which my PC is turned on and it runs fine for a couple of hours, or even days. But, randomly in a day while I'm using it, my monitor just goes black, saying Display Not Found on the screen. On the other hand, my fans keep running.

Sometimes, I even wait a couple of days not using this pc, just to test it again later. And, all of that repeats, I'm able to use the pc for a couple of hours or days, and then the display goes off with the fans still running. Some stuff I've already tried:

1. I tested the monitor on other pcs, it works fine in all of them.
2. I tried running using just the necessary: RAM, Hard drive, Processor,
   I even lowered the number of fans I have, no success.

This problem of no display happens when I try to use on-board graphics, or if I try to use other PCI graphics cards I have, both cases lead me to this black screen. Does anyone there can give me a hint? Because, I'm starting to consider that this might be a motherboard problem.

Comment: One thing it might help to discover when you can't see, is if your operating system is still running? You could use sound to discover that. if it is windows ? you could also make sure sounds exist for device connect , device disconnect, and device failed to connect. even a monitor disconnecting could play that sound, which might provide clues.  When you apply a different video device, I wonder if your disabling or removing the other device, to do the testing? What is the motherboard or computer model? You could use benchs like prime or furmark to torture things to see what work may cause it?

Comment: Have you tried booting into safe mode and uninstalling all the graphics drivers and allowing windows to try and re-detect them?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years old, but did you have an AMD CPU? If you did, it might have been related to [this problem](https://community.amd.com/thread/244440), in which AMD systems with more than 2 CPU-temperature-sensing programs running randomly crash to a black screen with fans at default speeds. Check it and see if it matches.